# MSQL password is working when login from MySQL console but same password is not working when trying to connect DB from PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code which I am using to connect my database. My credentials are perfectly working when directly login with MySQL console but the same is not working when trying to connect DB from my PHP code.

> Error ;PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user

```
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'HappaningsDb';
    $username = 'SIDSAHU3';
    $password = 'sid';
    $conn =null;

    //$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    //  $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

   // Check connection
   if($link == false){
   die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

   // Attempt insert query execution
   $sql = "insert into Question_data(QUESTION_ENG,OP_ENG, TOPIC_ID, CAT_ID, IS_PREMIUM, IS_HIN, 
   QUESTION_HIN ,OP_HIN, ANSWER, CREATE_USER,CREATE_DT,UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DT)values('hsdvhbsvsvk', 
   'dhvjd','1','1','N','N','','','2','sid',curdate(),'','');";
   if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   echo "Records added successfully.";
   } else{
   echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }

  // Close connection
   mysqli_close($link);
```

Please find attached screenshot:
[image: Please find attached screenshot]

Comment: don't  post your pwd  ..

Comment: That is the dummy password not the actual

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user.. This is the error which i am getting also i have attached the screenshot

Comment: Can someone please help me out with this issue

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `mysqli_error($conn);` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: You may have created a user in one database and connecting to another

Comment: thank you for the info , but this is my dummy code where i am trying to connect DB but getting Access denied error.

Comment: I have created the user with in PHP mysql and not in external Mysql :(

Answer (score -1):

User SIDSAHU3 could be restricted to Local host

From your CLI, try creating user with %

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

Comment: As suggested, i have created the new user with % host .. now i a getting below error   mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in

Comment: $servername = '%';
  $db_name = 'HappaningsDb';
  $username = 'SIDSAHU7';
  $password = 'sid12345';
  $conn =null;

//$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
 // $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

Comment: Server Name = localhost or name of the server.

Comment: i have tried that as well but still getting the same error. :(

Comment: To isolate its nothing to do with PDO can you try with MySQLi

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: @siddharthsahu did  the solution mentioned on top of the page worked ?

Comment: no it is not working